# How to calculate f(x) of a 6th degree function

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, polynomial-math, polynomials

I'm stuck on solving a little problem in python.
I have 7 random points and i have to interpolate a 6th degree function that passes through them.
So, first of all I need to find the right polynomial and then I'm given a certain f(x) to calculate.
Well, I'm not a pro in math but here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def langrange_polynomial(X, Y):
    def L(i):
        return lambda x: np.prod([(x-X[j])/(X[i]-X[j]) for j in range(len(X)) if i != j]) * Y[i]
    Sx = [L(i) for i in range(len(X))]  # summands
    return lambda x: np.sum([s(x) for s in Sx])

# cut something

# Here i get the points with a function
(X, Y) = read_data()
F = langrange_polynomial(X, Y)
```

And then, just to see the result, i create a plot.

```
x_range = np.linspace(X[0], X[-1], 100)
plt.plot(X, Y, 'ro')
plt.plot(x_range, map(F, x_range))
plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
plt.ylabel(r'$F(x)$')
plt.title('Lagrange polynomial interpolation')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Now, i found this code on the web and it looks like it find the right polynomial.
From what i understand the capital F is the actual polynomial, am i right?
and if so, how can I calculate f(x) with a user defined 'x'?

Let's say i have this:

```
x   y

1   -1
2   0
3   -23
4   -25
5   15
6   -7
7   23
```

and i want to find f(6.09)

How should i proceed?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lagrange_polynomial` returns a function that takes in a single argument. So if you're just looking to evaluate it at a particular point `user_defined_x` I think you just want

```
(X, Y) = read_data()
F = langrange_polynomial(X, Y)
print F(user_defined_x)
```